# Display images from Assets with JSON - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am making a WP8 application with a lot of local content in my Assets folder. So I am using a JSON file stored in the a JSON folder.

I have been able to parse the JSON to C# very easily and now I am trying to display the data in a list. I had no problem with displaying the title but I am unable to display an image, even with the filename I am got.

My images are stored in "Assets/Content/mediaXXX.jpg";

**ListViewModel :**

```
 public class ListViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Subtitle { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage ListImage { get; set; }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
 <ListBox Margin="0,1,0,0"
                 Height="730"
                 x:Name="MainList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="120"
                      Width="480">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Source="{Binding ListImage}"
                               Margin="12"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill"
                               Width="130"/>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ListItemTitle"
                                           Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ListItemSubTitle"
                                       Text="{Binding Subtitle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**And my C# page**

```
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/Content/" + photo.filename + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    l.ListImage = image;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code should work.  Only problems that might occur is your `ListBox` databinding is incorrectly defined.

I don't see any `.ItemsSource =` or `ItemsSource={Binding some_collection}`

Another thing is make sure that `photo.filename` is returning the correct file.

Set a  string debug_string = "Assets/Content/" + photo.filename + ".jpg";

Make sure everything is correct.

---

Last thing is to make sure the files are actually in the Assets Folder inside the project and its

`BuildAction` is set to `Content`

like so

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this last step cost me hours =)